# createRequest returns array instead of class

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to retrieve information on users using the [Microsoft Graph Library for PHP](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php).

But this code runs into the error `Trying to get property 'getGivenName' of non-object`.

```
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users")
              ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
              ->execute();
```

This is due to the fact, that `$user` is an array instead of an object!? What is wrong with the SDK (or my code)?

Is there any better documentation for the SDK???

Answer (score 2):

> This is due to the fact, that $user is an array instead of an object!?

That's right, since the [endpoint  `GET Users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) returns *the list of users*, in the provided example:

```
 $users = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users")
        ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
        ->execute();
```

`$users` contains an array of objects of [`Microsoft\Graph\Model\User` type](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Model/User.php), and

```
 $givenName = $users[0]->getGivenName();
```

gives `GivenName` property of *first item in array*.

A specific user could be requested  via [`GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0):

```
   $user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/{$userId}")
        ->setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
        ->execute();
```

In that case `$user` object is of [`Microsoft\Graph\Model\User` type](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/src/Model/User.php):

```
   $givenName = $user->getGivenName();
```

**Update**

`setReturnType` function accept Microsoft Graph API entity type name, in your example it appears `Model\User` points to type which doesn't belong to `Microsoft\Graph\Model` namespace and as a result JSON response is not getting deserialized into class instance.

Instead of

```
setReturnType(Model\User::class)
```

try to specify fully qualified class name:

```
setReturnType(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
```

Comment: I've already tried this:
```
$user = $graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/owagner@ad-libitum.info")
              ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
              ->execute();
```
This does not deliver an arry but an object - as intended.

But I get the error `Undefined property: Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::$getGivenName` when executing `$givenName = $user->getGivenName();`.

Comment: sorry, still the same error: `Undefined property: Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::$getGivenName`

Comment: By the way: the debugger says, my `$user={Microsoft\Graph\Model\user}` and in the user.php there is `public function getGivenName()`.

Comment: i got the same error, Undefined property: Microsoft\Graph\Model\Message::$contentType